# Calculation of database cells values

Tags: c#, database, division, cells

I have a database with a table, containing two integer fields.

When I try to get a percentage (fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB)), the value is 0.

```
double percentage = fieldA+fieldB // WORKS; 5+5=10
double percentage = fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB) // DOES NOT WORK; 5+5=0
```

So what's the problem here? Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB)` you get 5/10, which as an integer is truncated to 0, you have to do double division if you want 0.5 as a result.
i.e. something like this:

```
double percentage = (double)fieldA/(fieldA+fieldB)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do assume `fieldA` and `fieldB` are integers? If yes, you should be aware that dividing two integers results in an integer, too, no matter what is on the left side of the equation.

So dividing `fieldA` by `(fieldA+fieldB)` results in a value < 1 which results in zero. See [Integer Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Division_of_integers) on Wikipedia.

To correct the issue, simply cast at least one operand to a floating point type like e.g.:

```
double percentage = fieldA/(double)(fieldA+fieldB)
```

Comment: I tried using "int percentage" too, but also throws the same result. and I tried to write this: int percentage = Convert.ToInt32(fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB)); Also doesnt work

Comment: @DinoVelić that is the wrong idea, you want a value between 0 and 1, which is not an integer but a double. Therefore you have to cast one of your integer values to a double in order for it to be seen as double division (see other answers above)

Comment: @DinoVelić Try converting _before_ getting the full result. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since fieldA and fieldB are integers, the expression `fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB)`is of the form `int / int` which means you will use integer division, in this case - `5/10 = 0`, as integer division solves `x = am + b`, and in this case `5 = a*10 + b` which means `a = 0, b = 5`

You can do however:

```
double percentage = (double)fieldA / (fieldA+fieldB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to cast the fields as doubles before applying the operation

Answer (score 1):

try this :  double percentage = (double)fieldA/(double)(fieldA+fieldB)

Comment: I know I am picking nits but you don't necessarily have to cast both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

if both fields are integer, then the addition of the two integer results also integer.
Try this

float result = (float)((A*100)/(B+A));

Answer: result = 50.0